# UTF-8 in command prompt

Tags: java, command-line

hello 
i want to run java code in command prompt that read UTF-8

how can i do that

Answer (score 14):

fire up your java with

```
 java -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 <Your class Name>
```

Comment: Are you executing exactly what I wrote?  ie. java Your.class -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 ?  If so, that would be your problem. Your.class is supposed to be replaced with the class that you have written.

Comment: -D  not _D see: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/java.html#standard

Comment: I believe that should be "java -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 Client" where Client is the class with main().  No '.class' and the system property needs to come first.  Otherwise it's treated as an argument to main().

Comment: Setting encoding I/O using `file.encoding` has side-effects: http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=4163515

Answer (score 2):

There are methods in Java classes that accept a charset. See: InputStreamReader(java.io.InputStream, java.nio.charset.Charset) for instance.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html

But make sure you read Java Internationalization FAQ first, so you will understand how Java handles Unicode:

http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/core/basic/intl/faq.jsp